# How to receive 3gp file from android and decode it using python?

Tags: python, 3gp

I'm trying to receive a 3gp file from android and use the values in to inference a machine learning model in my server. The server codes are in python.

When I open the file I received using the code below,

```
AudioSegment.from_file(BytesIO(posted_data), format="3gp")
```

The outputs are values that are too big for a normal audio.
I think this is because the android encoded the values with MediaRecorder's AMR_NB codec, but was not decoded properly in server. Is there anyway I can properly decode the bytes I received in python server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) is widely recognized as a Swiss army knife of audio/video conversion. It has [Python bindings](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python). I don't know the quality of those bindings, but if the conversion is meant as a one-off thing, you could also consider using the very mature FFmpeg program to convert your file to uncompressed audio (like WAV) before processing it with your code. Even the [Python standard library can deal with WAV](https://docs.python.org/3/library/wave.html).